# How to scroll past the last link in a HTMLComponent (LWUIT 1.5)?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, html-components

How can I scroll past the last link in a HTMLComponent? I am using LWUIT 1.5.
Moreover if the link spans over multiple lines, it stops on the first line, so the whole link is not visible.

HTML file for testing: http://bit.ly/uJ8RbN

UPDATE: The issue is here http://java.net/jira/browse/LWUIT-487.

Any workaround tips before the issue gets resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Scrolling past the last link works properly in our test cases although its always possible there is a bug in the HTMLComponent implementation. If you found such a case please file an issue in the lwuit issue tracker in the [LWUIT website](http://lwuit.java.net) and include the HTML that triggered the problem. The same probably applies to the long links issue.

Comment: Yes, in case there is more text bellow the last link, users are unable to scroll down. Also if the link wraps it just scrolls to the first line (of the last link). (For scrolling I am using standard arrow keys of the phone, it neither work in the standard emulator.)

Comment: You should disable the cyclic scrolling of the parent form. See the lwuit browser demo and see whether the issue reproduces there.

Comment: Sorry, but the `Browser` demo is not using the `HTMLComponent` but the `BrowserComponent`, which uses native browser implementation. (I have the cyclic scrolling disabled.)

Comment: The browser demo in LWUITDemo has an option of using the native component which you can choose not to use. However, if you are using MIDP there is no native component option so it will always use the lightweight version. I was referring to the web browser demo which is not the LWUIT demo and never uses the native browser even when its available, it allows you to load arbitrary HTML pages and has a web browser UI with back/forward and an address bar.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I see that it is using own extended version of `HTMLComponent` the `ExtHTMLComponent`. But still the Browser demo has the same problem. (I am trying it on ClamshellCldcPhone and DefaultCldcPhone emulators.)

Comment: The reason for the ExtHTMLComponent is to enable support for pointer functionality on low end devices and workaround some issues in older versions of LWUIT. If you are experiencing a problem you need to include the HTML source causing said problem otherwise no one would fix that problem.

Comment: I have added a test file to the question.

Comment: Thanks, Ofir will probably followup in the issue tracker.

Comment: Ok, do you have any hint for a workaround -- which can be added e.g. to ExtHTMLComponent?

Comment: Anything new on this issue? Workaround at least?

Comment: I suggest you follow up in the LWUIT database issue. This is assigned to Ofir and that sort of issue is something only he can solve.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to add an empty button to the end of the form, format the button to look like the background, without borders etc. This way after the HtmlComponent there is still a button that doesnt have focus but allows you scroll to the bottom.

Comment: Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim answers to multiple questions, these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community. If you're doing this then it usually means the questions are duplicates so flag them as such instead.